# writing a large stream to a file in C#.Net 64K by 64K

Tags: c#, filestream

Please suggest me a good method that can be used to write a stream into a file.

I just need a simple c# function that can take a stream as input and do the job..
I need to do this for very large files ie files > 4GB.

Can this be done better using linq,extension methods etc?

Please provide me a good utility function that can also return the progress in percentage through yield.

Edit: I know about looping through a byte[] and writing it to a file. I've tried File.WriteAllBytes method. But,I'm just looking for a very nice way of doing it using linq,yield and extension methods.

Comment: @Ladislav, I already have code to write from stream to a file. I mean I know we can just loop through the bytes and write it or even use File.Write method.

Comment: @Oded, I need a neat reusable function written using modern techniques

Comment: may i know which kind of application you are creating for which you need such large file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit**: Here is a utility function that should do the trick:

**Update**: Changed second parameter to file name

```
    public delegate void ProgressCallback(long position, long total);
    public void Copy(Stream inputStream, string outputFile, ProgressCallback progressCallback)
    {
        using (var outputStream = File.OpenWrite(outputFile))
        {
            const int bufferSize = 4096;
            while (inputStream.Position < inputStream.Length)
            {
                byte[] data = new byte[bufferSize];
                int amountRead = inputStream.Read(data, 0, bufferSize);
                outputStream.Write(data, 0, amountRead);

                if (progressCallback != null)
                    progressCallback(inputStream.Position, inputStream.Length);
            }
            outputStream.Flush();
        }
    }
```

Comment: @aKzenT, Thanks..but just one more thing (sorry i forgot to mention this before), itseems I need to write 64k by 64k as per MSDN's documentation for writing files transferred through a stream in WCF

Comment: Just adjust the buffer size to 64k... but can you tell me to which you are referring exactly? do you have a link?

Comment: Quoting it so you can see "suppose your service must receive files up to 4 GB in size and store them on the local disk. Suppose also that your memory is constrained in such a way that you can only buffer 64 KB of data at a time". It's from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx

Comment: @aKzenT, I think I misunderstood it. It mentions "suppose". Sorry again aKzen. So,I guess it's only an example scenario and doesn't always matter.

Comment: I changed the second parameter to take a file name instead

Comment: Thank you aKzenT. I haven't tested this yet though but I believe this will work. Is it possible to use the yield keywords instead of a delegate?